# Azure 'Web App on Linux' app service continuous deployment with Github is broken

Tags: node.js, azure, github, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I had successfully deployed a simple node.js application on Azure's Web App on Linux service from a private Github repository ( Using `Deployment options` in Azure's portal UI).

But after pushing a new change to the Github repo the continuous deployment does not work. Entering the `Deployment options` in Azure's portal UI shows a sad cloud icon

[image]

and error message:

`ContinuousDeploymentListPart WEBSITESEXTENSION`in Azure's portal.

Tried to "Disconnect and reconnect my source control" several times for a few days in a row.

All requests ended with a timeout:

`Failed to set up deployment source
Failed to set up deployment source for web app <MY_APP_NAME>, using GitHub. Heuristics indicate WebApiClient request timed out. Uri: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/...
Timeout: 00:01:00`

Tried also to remove the ssh keys Azure added to Github account, but it did not help with re-setting the deployment source on Azure.

Also tried creating another, clean instance of Azure web app. The deployement worked for the initial fetching of data, but ended in the same issue when tried to push new changes to the repo.

- How to fix the current issue?
- Is there another way to setting the github <-> azure deployment integration?

EDIT:

Trying to change the Deployment source on any site with that error results in the following error
**The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.**:

```
    Failed to set up deployment source for web app <MY_APP_NAME>, using GitHub. {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.TrackerContext.<GetResponseAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.<GetSSHKey>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.GitHubSiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass35e.<<UpdateSiteSourceControl>b__359>d__363.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl).","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.TrackerContext.<GetResponseAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.<GetSSHKey>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.GitHubSiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass35e.<<UpdateSiteSourceControl>b__359>d__363.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl)."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"05007","MessageTemplate":"Repository '{0}' operation failed with {1}.","Parameters":["UpdateSiteSourceControl","System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.TrackerContext.<GetResponseAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.<GetSSHKey>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.GitHubSiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass35e.<<UpdateSiteSourceControl>b__359>d__363.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl)"],"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.TrackerContext.<GetResponseAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.<GetSSHKey>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.GitHubSiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass35e.<<UpdateSiteSourceControl>b__359>d__363.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl)."}}],"Innererror":null}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your app name, [privately](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) if you like? Also, is your Github repo public/shareable? It sounds like you've reproduced this pretty easily and I'd like to see if I can do the same in order to investigate.

Comment: Hello @nlawalker, unfortunately I cannot share the repo. Perhaps it would be beneficial to note, that the repo is within Github organization's team. I also created an app: debugging-github-deployment, check any of the web app on linux app.

Comment: @nlawalker: Is there a way I can check any logs for kudu? How to restart that deployment or even whole docker image it works on via portal? is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @nlawalker: the issue does not seem to be code related. One of the sites is deployed and working fine with only the deployment crashed (no new pushes can get deployed).

Comment: @Blaise To see any log file from Kudu you can use the CMD. After you have opened the CMD prompt, open the folder called `LogFiles` and now you should be able to see the log files. If needed, you can also download them.

Comment: @lorenzomontanari: I try to access the Kudu diagnostic console, but the link to it from Azure portal times-out. Nothing is shown - blank page, no Kudu. I can access that bash however and it works fine on a newly created web app instance, but before setting any deployment option... So my main concern is now: can I set the deployement from github in some other way than through web portal??

Comment: @Blaise Well it's a strange situation... It seems it's an Azure bug... No the only way to change these kind of settings is through the Azure Portal. You could try to delete manually all the web site files and see if it works. If it don't, i would deploy another web app, set up the deployment from Github (with the same repo) and see if it works (also pushing something new). If it works fine i would deploy again the main website (the one that now doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an answer from Azure's support forum [to this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13ba4347-a975-458e-843d-05921d37623f/web-apps-on-linuxs-continuous-deployement-with-github-does-not-work-for-me?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview):

> The Kudu site associated with your main site was not starting up, and
>   communication with one of its API endpoints is required for creation
>   of a source control hook.
>   (...) **I should also recommend - for large application deployments with lots of source code, many dependencies and files and/or compute or disk-heavy deployment requirements, you may want to try containerizing your application.**

and also:

> **Deployment from source via Kudu does not scale well in some scenarios.**

So if you'd also would like to *containerize your application* you can find more info following the links below:

- https://dzone.com/articles/docker-for-devs-containerizing-your-application
- https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/